# How to use mongodb $comment

Tags: mongodb

I want to add comments to my aggregation pipeline. They are described here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/query/comment/ but I cannot make them work.

With

```
db.aCollection.aggregate([{"$match":{"a":true}, "$comment":"some comment"}])
```

I get error

```
A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.
```

And with

```
db.aCollection.aggregate([{"$match":{"a":true}}, {"$comment":"some comment"}])
```

I get error

```
$comment is not allowed or the syntax is incorrect, see the Atlas documentation for more information
```

I'm querying MongoDB Atlas with v6.0.8

Comment: Looks like your nesting is wrong in both cases according to the documentation that you linked. Place it as a sibling field of `a` inside of the object specified to `$match`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the comment in the same level as `a`:

```
db.aCollection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      a: 1,
      $comment: "some comment"
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XkAFZS-zprK)

Comment: Okay, this way it works but not with all operators which is sad and makes it useless.

Comment: according to the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/query/comment/#std-label-ex-comment-agg-expression), on aggregation pipeline, currently only the `$match` stage is supported.

Comment: Which operator are you trying to use it with? In any case this answer should be accepted as it solves the original issue posted here

Comment: @MáriusRak I believe the purpose of `$comment` is to place comments in the [profile log](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/command/profile/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.profile) and the [MongoDB log](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/log-messages/).  It isn't meant to comment aggregation pipeline stages.